# How to insert unsigned char* variable into std::string?

Tags: c++, string

I try to include unsigned char variable into std::string.it throws compiletime error.

```
unsigned char* SrvName;
std::string m_sSMTPSrvName;
//srvName contains "207.45.255.45"

m_sSMTPSrvName.insert(0, SrvName);
```

**Error**

```
   error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::insert(unsigned int,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const unsigned char *' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'
```

Comment: @all:Check the Error.Tell me the reason for that Error.this might solve my problem.

Comment: The reason for the error is because `std::string` is typically defined as `typedef basic_string<char> string;`. It is meant to hold `char` values, not `unsigned char`. You will continue to get errors and warnings by mixing `std::string` and `unsigned char`.

Comment: You could either change your declaration to `char* SrvName` or add casts everywhere to suppress errors and warnings. I suggest the first option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you use `unsigned char*` in the first place?

Anyway, if `SrvName` is null-terminated, you can do:

```
    std::string m_sSMTPSrvName=reinterpret_cast<const char*>(SrvName);
```

Or if you know `SrvName`'s length, you can do:

```
    std::string m_sSMTPSrvName(SrvName, SrvName + Length);
```

---

EDIT:

After reading your new comment, looks like what you actually want is to convert the numbers in the array to a string that represents an IP address. You can do it this way:

```
#include <sstream>

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    std::stringstream out;
    out << (int)SrvName[i];
    m_sSMTPSrvName += out.str();

    if (i < 3)
    {
        m_sSMTPSrvName += ".";
    }
}
```

Comment: you shouldnot typecast .because the string contains "207.45.255.45".so if you typecast then 207 and 255 values are changed into -49 and -97 respectively.

Comment: @user1004807, no it won't change the numeric values. The string literal "207.45.255.45" contains ASCII characters, not integers.

Comment: @user1004807 but it's a string, so 207 is not one character but three.

Comment: @Igor:It stored like this srvname[0] = 207,srvname[1] = 45.

Comment: @user1004807, if `SrvName` really is a __character string__ the number 207 should be stored as three ASCII values 0x32 0x30 0x37

Comment: @user1004807: that is not the correct way to store digits into a string. Is the problem that you have the octets and want to put them into a string?

Comment: @igor: +1 for your solution.I want like these.Thanks for your info

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the `unsigned char* SrvName`. It should be `char* SrvName`

If you are insisting that it be `unsigned char*`, Then cast it.
`m_sSMTPSrvName.insert(0, (char*)SrvName);`

In any case, if the value of `SrvName` is `207.45.255.45` you should just make it `char*`.
You might be confusing the int value 207, and the string value of 207.

207 as a string is 3 chars, 58 (2), 48 (0), 55 (7)

Comment: @ltsik: what are you trying to say?it won't solve my problem.

Comment: if your problem is that you want the string m_sSMTPSrvName to contain SrvName then it will. Unless you didn't write your question correctly

Comment: @ltsik: In my application,the declaration will be in some other .h file.so, I use insert function to insert the string.

Comment: It doesnt matter where the declaration is, you can still initialize it in a different file, but nevermind. I updated the answer.

Comment: That is what my question.How to include unsigned char into string?If i typecast unsigned char into char then values above 127 is changed to some other value.so you shouldn't typecast and change.

Comment: If you are using more than the ASCII character set you need to use something else than `char`, for example `wchar_t`. But this is a totally different question.

Comment: @user1004807: you are incorrect. Using `char*` allows `"207.45.255.45"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `m_sSMTPSrvName.append(SrvName)` or `m_sSMTPSrvName.assign(SrvName)`, depending on desired behaviour. Mind you, you should have trouble with your original approach either, so I'm not *certain* this will solve your problem.

Reference docs [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/).